# How to add new roles to ngx-admin existing login page

Tags: angular, ngx-admin

How can I customize the existing login module by adding custom roles. I wasn't not able to find any specific documentation on the login module. Maybe this is already supported ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to copy the login.component code and basically create a custom one based on that.